# Backpack-for-Laravel installation is hanging at 'Creating users table'

Tags: laravel-backpack

After running composer (require backpack/crud) and then

```
php artisan backpack:install
```

the installation freezes at Step 1: Creating users table.  The status stays as RUNNING forever.

My environment is PHP 8.3.1, Laravel 10.48.4.0, and the two backpack package modules (/basset, and /crud) are 1.3.0 and 6.7.1 respectively.

What do I do/where do I look to solve this problem?

Thanks/Tom

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check your database server is working correctly, and you have to configure the .env first. If you still have a problem, you can try the manual process https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-how-to#how-to-manually-install-backpack

Cheers.

Comment: The public-side of the site is running just fine and as it's fetching content from the database, I have to assume that the database server is also working correctly.  I tried the manual process but I'm still getting a Error 500 response when I seek to log into Backpack.  Should I delete backpack and start over?  What's the best way to remove backpack from the server?  Thanks/Tom